# System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom - Duplicate assembly name - Need Better workaround

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

I'm working on a utility that reports the version number from a .net assembly, given its path.  It uses `assy = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path)` to load the assembly, then parses `assy.GetName.ToString()` to learn the version number.

This works fine, as long as I don't try to load 2 different files with the same assembly name in the same invocation of the program.  If I do that, `LoadFrom()` always returns the same Assembly object, even if the files are actually different versions.

This is **documented** behavior, see the "Remarks" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.80).aspx

The utility needs to run with .Net 2.0 under Windows CE; it's an industrial application running on a Symbol (now Zebra) MT2000 handheld scanner.  This means that I don't have the choice to use `Load()` or `LoadFile()`.

The obvious workaround is to invoke the utility twice and compare the results, but that's inconvenient for several reasons.  Anybody have any better ideas?

Comment: This is one of the very, *very* few reasons to use LoadFile().  Not available on CF, bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName`method, which doesn't Load the Assembly but causes the file to be opened and closed. More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("YourExe.exe");
  var versionOfAssembly = assemblyName.Version;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is not available in Windows CE.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the name of the assembly, you can use method `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`. This method loads distinct assemblies even if they have the same assembly name.

```
    var assm = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(path);
    var name = assm.GetName().ToString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is not available in Windows CE.